# Print at maximum n characters per line, but no cut

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have this problem: I have a text file, where every line has different number of characters, like this:

```
aaaa
bbbbbbbbb
cc
```

Now I want to generate a new text file, where a line has at maximum N characters, but no content is missing. So, something like this (e.g. each line should have at maximum 4 characters):

```
aaaa
bbbb
bbbb
b
cc
```

Is this possible with `sed`, `awk`, `grep` or other tools in combination with a one-liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fold -w4 yourfile
```

## Output

```
aaaa
bbbb
bbbb
b
cc
```

Comment: Unfortunately with current versions of GNU `fold`, that folds at 4 bytes (actually 4 columns (handling BS, CR and TAB at least), but failing to handle multi-byte (or zero-width or double-width) characters), not characters.

Comment: But the OP wants a `text` file modified....

Comment: Yes, but see `echo éééééé | fold -w 4` in a UTF-8 locale on a GNU system for instance.

Comment: I used this solution, because this was the fastest. But the other solutions are also nice :)

Answer (score 3):

## Perl

```
perl -lne 'print for /.{1,4}|^$/g' yourfile
```

## Sed1

```
sed -e '
   s/..../&\n/
   /\n$/P;//d
   P;D
' yourfile
```

## Sed2

```
sed -e '
   s/..../&\n/g
   s/\n$//
' yourfile
```

## Bash

```
while IFS= read -r l; do
   case $l in '' ) echo; continue ;; esac
   while case $l in '' ) break ;; esac; do
      echo "${l:0:4}"
      l=${l:4:${#l}}
   done
done < yourfile
```

Answer (score 2):

All time classic grep:

```
$ echo "$a"
aaaa
bbbbbbbbb
cc

$ echo "$a" |egrep -o '(.){1,4}'
aaaa
bbbb
bbbb
b
cc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's_\(....\).*_\1_' /path/to/input
```

Anything shorter than four characters won't be touched; anything longer will be truncated.